# How to solve geodjango url conflict for geojson data?

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

I have the urls

```
url(r'^geojson.data/$', geojson_provinces, name='geojson_provinces'),
url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Account,properties=('species','listvalues',)), name='data'),

url(r'^extdata.data/$', existingData_APFT, name='existingData_APFT'),
url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Existing_Data_APFT,properties=('species','listvalues',)), name='extdata'),
```

FRom the two urls Im displaying different geojson data on map. But When I run

```
  http://localhost:8000/extdata.data/
```

The geojson data of (geojson.data) is getting dispalyed. I read from the docs that django checks the order but can it be done order independent?

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include,patterns
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from pft.views import*
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from pft.models import Account,Existing_Data_APFT
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView

urlpatterns =patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'',include('pft.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'), # If user is not login it will redirect to login page
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
    url(r'^home/$', home),
    url(r'^$',geojson),
    url(r'^index/',index),
    url(r'^submit', submit),
    url(r'^pft',pft),
    url(r'^geojson.data/$', geojson_provinces, name='geojson_provinces'),
    url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Account,properties=('species','listvalues',)), name='data'),
 url(r'^extdata.data/$', existingData_APFT, name='existingData_APFT'),
    url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Existing_Data_APFT,properties=('species','listvalues',)), name='extdata'),
 url(r'^potpft.data/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pot_pft.html'), name='extract_raster_points'),

    url(r'^datapotg.geojson/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Account,properties=('species','rastvalues',)), name='datapotg'),
    url(r'^csv',add_multiple_accounts,name='add_multiple_accounts'),
    url(r'^traits',add_traits,name='add_traits'),

    (r'^', include('pft.urls')),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a URL conflict. Are you sure `existingData_APFT` view returns the correct data? What happens when you comment the first line (geojson.data) out?

Comment: If I comment the line geojson.data line,this url - url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Account,properties=('species','listvalues',)), name='data'), is getting executed.

Comment: Is this the `urls.py` for the project or an app? Can you edit your question and post your whole urls.py (including import statements)

Comment: this is urls.py for the project. I have attached the complete urls.py

Comment: You also include `pft.urls` at the root level, can you also post the source to it?

Comment: What does it mean? I'm new to geodjango